# NTP not syncing

Tags: linux, ntp

I need some help regarding the NTP daemon.
I have problem to make ntpd sync with any external NTP servers.

Raspberry IP is 192.168.10 (eth0).
To simplify troubleshooting I am using the default configuration.
Here are some output from the troubleshooting:

**Any idea what this "p" means under the "t"(type) ?
I cant find it in the documentation.**

```
# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002

# ntpq -c as
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 14681  8811   yes  none  none    reject    mobilize  1
  2 14682  8811   yes  none  none    reject    mobilize  1
  3 14683  8811   yes  none  none    reject    mobilize  1
  4 14684  8811   yes  none  none    reject    mobilize  1
```

All NTP servers are rejected, but why?

---

```
ntpq> rv 14681
associd=14681 status=8811 conf, bcast, sel_reject, 1 event, mobilize,
**srcadr=0.0.0.0**, srcport=0, srchost="0.debian.pool.ntp.org",
**dstadr=0.0.0.0**, dstport=0, leap=11, stratum=16, precision=-19,
rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=0.000, refid=POOL, reftime=(no time),
rec=(no time), reach=000, unreach=0, hmode=3, pmode=0, hpoll=6, ppoll=10,
headway=18, flash=1400 peer_dist, peer_unreach, keyid=0, offset=+0.000,
delay=0.000, dispersion=16000.000, jitter=0.002,
filtdelay=     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00,
filtoffset=   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00,
filtdisp=   16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0
ntpq> 

ntpq> rv 14683
associd=14683 status=8811 conf, bcast, sel_reject, 1 event, mobilize,
srcadr=0.0.0.0, srcport=0, srchost="2.debian.pool.ntp.org",
dstadr=0.0.0.0, dstport=0, leap=11, stratum=16, precision=-19,
rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=0.000, refid=POOL, reftime=(no time),
rec=(no time), reach=000, unreach=0, hmode=3, pmode=0, hpoll=6, ppoll=10,
headway=5, flash=1400 peer_dist, peer_unreach, keyid=0, offset=+0.000,
delay=0.000, dispersion=16000.000, jitter=0.002,
filtdelay=     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00,
filtoffset=   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00   +0.00,
filtdisp=   16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0
```

Source and destination is 0.0.0.0
Is that correct?

I have tried to reinstall the ntp package without success.
Nothing is blocking ntp towards internet. This is a a tcpdump capture:

```
tcpdump udp port ntp
....
22:22:25.542319 IP 192.168.1.10.ntp > sucker.mfa.gr.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
22:22:25.542636 IP 192.168.1.10.ntp > ntp1.xe.gr.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
22:22:25.550535 IP sucker.mfa.gr.ntp > 192.168.1.10.ntp: NTPv4, Server, length 48
22:22:25.550933 IP ntp1.xe.gr.ntp > 192.168.1.10.ntp: NTPv4, Server, length 48
22:22:27.551988 IP 192.168.1.10.ntp > skevosd.arx.gr.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
22:22:27.569547 IP skevosd.arx.gr.ntp > 192.168.1.10.ntp: NTPv4, Server, length 48
22:23:29.597352 IP 192.168.1.10.ntp > mail.l0nax.org.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
22:23:29.651378 IP mail.l0nax.org.ntp > 192.168.1.10.ntp: NTPv4, Server, length 48
22:23:30.542338 IP 192.168.1.10.ntp > ipa225.1.tellas.gr.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
22:23:31.542359 IP 192.168.1.10.ntp > 62.1.105.163.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
```

There is no networking issue :

```
#ntpdate -d 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
18 Mar 22:37:20 ntpdate[12713]: ntpdate 4.2.8p12@1.3728-o (1)
Looking for host 0.debian.pool.ntp.org and service ntp
217.114.59.66 reversed to ns0.luns.net.uk
host found : ns0.luns.net.uk
transmit(217.114.59.66)
receive(217.114.59.66)
transmit(178.17.160.12)
receive(178.17.160.12)
transmit(188.114.116.1)
receive(188.114.116.1)
transmit(50.205.244.21)
receive(50.205.244.21)
transmit(217.114.59.66)
receive(217.114.59.66)
transmit(178.17.160.12)
receive(178.17.160.12)
transmit(188.114.116.1)
receive(188.114.116.1)
transmit(50.205.244.21)
receive(50.205.244.21)
transmit(217.114.59.66)
receive(217.114.59.66)
transmit(178.17.160.12)
receive(178.17.160.12)
transmit(188.114.116.1)
receive(188.114.116.1)
transmit(50.205.244.21)
receive(50.205.244.21)
transmit(217.114.59.66)
receive(217.114.59.66)
transmit(178.17.160.12)
receive(178.17.160.12)
transmit(188.114.116.1)
receive(188.114.116.1)
transmit(50.205.244.21)
receive(50.205.244.21)

server 217.114.59.66, port 123
stratum 2, precision -20, leap 00, trust 000
refid [157.44.176.4], root delay 0.005096, root dispersion 0.018936
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    e3fe3875.de4769f8  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:09.868
originate timestamp: e3fe3896.caf64aad  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:42.792
transmit timestamp:  e3fe3886.c6808fdd  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:26.775
filter delay:  0.08784  0.08081  0.08160  0.08055 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 15.99312 15.99007 15.99036 15.98993
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.08055, dispersion 0.00056
offset 15.989931

server 178.17.160.12, port 123
stratum 2, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [47.187.174.51], root delay 0.135544, root dispersion 0.242020
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    e3fe3606.d5c17d79  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:26:46.834
originate timestamp: e3fe3896.e85c0197  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:42.907
transmit timestamp:  e3fe3886.f9b363d2  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:26.975
filter delay:  0.09550  0.09355  0.09375  0.09328 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 15.89899 15.89840 15.89863 15.89838
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.09328, dispersion 0.00015
offset 15.898386

server 188.114.116.1, port 123
stratum 2, precision -24, leap 00, trust 000
refid [114.199.6.79], root delay 0.004318, root dispersion 0.038391
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    e3fe3296.0ea3aec5  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:12:06.057
originate timestamp: e3fe3897.30f08e38  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:43.191
transmit timestamp:  e3fe3887.2ce6549e  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:27.175
filter delay:  0.07771  0.07642  0.16254  0.07607 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 15.99090 15.99089 16.03402 15.99053
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.07607, dispersion 0.00569
offset 15.990531

server 50.205.244.21, port 123
stratum 2, precision -21, leap 00, trust 000
refid [50.205.244.28], root delay 0.000397, root dispersion 0.020447
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    e3fe37d0.ae162649  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:34:24.680
originate timestamp: e3fe3897.70b9e0e3  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:43.440
transmit timestamp:  e3fe3887.60196d98  Thu, Mar 18 2021 22:37:27.375
filter delay:  0.16942  0.16629  0.16681  0.16716 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 15.99488 15.99414 15.99416 15.99413
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.16629, dispersion 0.00009
offset 15.994145

18 Mar 22:37:27 ntpdate[12713]: step time server 188.114.116.1 offset 15.990531 sec

# timedatectl 
               Local time: Thu 2021-03-18 23:15:34 EET
           Universal time: Thu 2021-03-18 21:15:34 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Athens (EET, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Any idea why my ntp server cannot sync ?

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: What do you do with  timedatectl?

Comment: What u mean what I have? I have installed ntpd (apt-get install ntp) and I try to make it sync

Comment: I have added timedatectl output in the initial post.
thx

Comment: Try `sudo timedatectl set-ntp true`

Comment: The service is still inactive in timedatectl. I think this is not related as ntp service is started independently.

Comment: There was an old post of the RPF forum that had something like only one service can run at once going by my memory BUT I could not find it last night TBH but sure I did not dream it :-( Would timedatectl block ntp?

Comment: The service is not running twice

Comment: Maybe I have to ask it into the Linux forum, as it is a generic ntp issue and not directly related to raspberry

Comment: Just came across this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=307328#p1840633 maybe it (and the rest of the thread) may help.

Answer (score 2):

The 'p' stands for Pool Source.

Not all Linux distribution manuals support this notation but the Debian version at [this page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ntp/ntpq.1.en.html) does. Specifically:

> - u: unicast or manycast client
> - b: broadcast or multicast client
> - p: pool source
> - l: local (reference clock)
> - s: symmetric (peer)
> - A: manycast server
> - B: broadcast server
> - M: multicast server